# How to assign values to Nested Json array

Tags: c#, json

I am using C#. I want the Json array in the below structure

```
"bed_configurations": [
           [{
             "type": "standard",
             "code": 3,
             "count": 1
             },
             {
              "type": "custom",
              "name": "Loft",
              "count": 1
             }]
        ]
```

Please any one can help me..

Comment: What is your goal, do you want to create such structure from class, create it with? specify a concrete thing you want to achieve and show us the code that you have developed so far.

Comment: Why do you need an array in array containing only one array in this json?

Comment: hi Mr.Rafal, I want to create the json array structure from class and i want to know how to create the class and how to assign the values from database to this structure.

Comment: Hi Mr.Rogalski, I want to send this structure to other third Party. That party want the json in this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `class` for desired `json`. Also you have to use `using Newtonsoft.Json;` for json converter. I've created an example, please check this.

CODE:

```
public class Header
{
    public List<List<Item>> bed_configurations { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

private static void getJSON()
{
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    items.Add(new Item() { type = "standard", code = 3, count = 1 });
    items.Add(new Item() { type = "custom", name = "Loft", count = 1 });

    Header ob = new Header();
    ob.bed_configurations = new List<List<Item>>() { items };

    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ob);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer. i'll try it in myside

Comment: Thank you so much. It is Working Properly.......

Comment: You are welcome!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach would be to create a class that resembles this structure, and use [Newtonsoft.JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize/deserialize the object to/from a json string.

```
public class BedConfiguration
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type {get; set;}
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public int Code {get; set;}
    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public int Count {get; set;}
}
```

And the whole json string is simply an array, within an array, of the class above (strangely). So you could populate a list of these `BedConfiguration`and then serialize them:

```
var configs = new List<List<BedConfiguration>>();
//Populate the list programmatically.
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(configs);
```

Similarly, you can turn the json string back into a list:

```
var configs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<BedConfiguration>>>(json);
```

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that it's an array within an array.